# Experimental CSS for IE: To hack or not to hack?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

There are some eye-candy experimental CSS like border-radius (rounded corners) and gradients that I wish to use on my page. Unfortunately Internet Explorer does not support any of that yet. At least border-radius is coming on IE9, no word on gradients yet.

So would you recommend just leaving IE alone (most of my users will be on FF or Chrome anyways) or use images to "fix" the presentation for IE? Is it even worth it? Because I know that not only is a pain in the behind but might also break styling on other browsers.

So, to hack or not to hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not want images, IE hacks or a seperate stylesheet you could always check out CSS3Pie: http://css3pie.com/. It's not perfect, especially not when you want some gradients & shadows but it can deal with rounded corners pretty easily. There are similar IE behaviors out there but I think this one has the most active development at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is a bit subjective, my answer would be not to hack. CSS3 was made to be backwards compatible, and that means it will degrade gracefully if a browser doesn't support it. That for me is the way it should be. I mean, why use CSS3 if you're still planning to hack it anyway? In that case just use the plain old CSS2 tricks like javascript rounded corners or images so you do't have to hack per se.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology quibble: using images to imitate CSS3 features in IE isn’t really hacking. Any visual effect that isn’t directly supported in CSS will need to be implemented in images.

But to answer your question, it depends:

- If few enough of your audience use IE, then you can ignore it. Figuring out how few is few enough is up to you/the site owners.
- If not:

  - If the `border-radius` effects aren’t a key part of the site’s branding, then I’d suggest you just let IE ignore them and use square corners. No-one browses the web with two browsers simultaneously, and no-one cares if your site looks a little bit different in IE 6, as long as the buttons are in the same place and everything works.
  - If they are a key part of the site’s branding, or your client insists on the site looking the same in IE 6, then you’ve got to achieve the look in IE 6. So, either:

    - use `border-radius`, and use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include a stylesheet for IE 8 and below with code to imitate the features
    - don’t bother with `border-radius` — use the code that works in IE for all browsers. This will avoid you having to maintain two sets of code, but it will mean that all browsers have to download the images you’re using for IE, thus making them perform slightly less well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its ever a choice between 'hacking' and not implementing it at all across all browsers, and I'm surprised nobody has mentioned one of the real life-saving 'feature' (I won't consider it a hack, since it is a brilliant method for backward compatibility): **Conditional Comments**

Not only does it help with annoying IE bugs, it also allows you to define less desirable, but still 100% valid methods for getting certain effects to work, like image gradients with `repeat-y` instead of CSS3 gradients, or tiled semi-transparent pngs for IE7 and 8. Really, if you want to, IE shouldn't be the *one single factor* that will limit your ability to experiment with CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

There are hacks and then there are hacks.  I interpret a "hack" as being something that exploits a flaw in the browser, such as the descendant selector hack in IE (using `>`).  Those types of things break when the browser is updated.

I don't consider using images to create nice drop shadows or gradients to be a hack.  It may not satisfy the requirements that you are doing everything semantically, and you may feel queasy about resorting to using an image for something that an image should not be required for, but the reality is that there's simply no choice - no way to do everything the clean, no-images way - if you want pretty gradients and shadows on the majority of people's browsers (Internet Explorer being that majority).

If you consider the rounded borders or gradients to be just optional eye-candy then by all means don't worry about IE.  But if you consider that it actually does make your design look good and you don't want the majority of your users* to miss out, then go for it.

*Depending on your audience, IE may or may not make up a majority of your audience I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on how important those features are to the look and feel of the site, or rather how important the client and design team feel they are. Additionally its a quation of how much is this going to bloat your markup and CSS - ie. depending on how the effects need to be built in the context of the design how much of a hassle is it going to be?

Normally in this case im in favor of progressive enhancment, ie. come up with something suitable but it doesnt need to be a 1-to-1 to the composite art. Again though, this is a decision you as a developer will ever really be in a position to make on your own (well, unless youre also the designer).